# RegExp, unicode, and javascript. How do I tell the difference between "\u306E" and the character "の"?

Tags: javascript, unicode

Lets say I have a JavaScript function that accepts a Unicode string as an argument:

`function eleFunc(str){
  ...

}`

How programatically inside the function can I determine whether it was called with a string containing a Unicode escape sequence, or an actual character? As in, whether it was called like:

`eleFunc("\u306E"); //the Unicode escape for "の"`

or

`eleFunc("の");　// the character itself`

Comment: What would be the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are only different in the source code. This information is not available during run time because the parser throws it away - both are turned into exactly the same JavaScript string by the parser.

What is it that you are really trying to do? Knowing how a string was presented in source code  (or if it even was in any source code to begin with) is not really useful thing for a function to know.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why a regexp might test true for the unicode escape, and false for the character.

Comment: @wasabiwimp either because you are using the regexp differently or misencoding the javascript file. You can try `alert("の")` and `alert("\u306e")` to see if you have an encoding screwup.

Comment: What encoding should my Javascript file be? I'm assuming UTF8?

Comment: @wasabiwimp Yes, but this implies many things. You need to save the javascript file physically in UTF-8 encoding. You need to serve your pages as UTF-8 (with HTTP header or meta tag) and ensure that the physical encoding of your web pages is UTF-8 as well. If this is too much to handle, you can keep using the unicode escapes.

Comment: I wanted to thank you Esailija, the webpage lacking the proper header turned out to be the issue. All of the files themselves were physically encoded correctly.

I should add that I was testing my Javascript using Jasmine, which by default the page "SpecRunner.html" used to run the tests does not have the meta tag in the page by default. Inserting it in the head section allowed my tests to all pass.